# Is it normal that bash stat() and access() much, before commands?

Tags: bash, stat, dash, syscalls

Running `strace` on the `bash` shell that is instructed to run `mkdir` provided this output which shows lots of stats prior to execve the actual `mkdir` binary:

```
BASH$> strace -f sh -c "bash -c \"mkdir /tmp\" 2>&1 | nl | grep -e "execve\|stat\|access" 
[.....]
  2766  [pid 17371] stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0750, st_size=17262, ...}) = 0
  2767  [pid 17371] stat("/usr/local/sbin/mkdir", 0x7ffd87aad0a0) = -1 ENOENT      2767 (No such file or directory)
  2768  [pid 17371] stat("/usr/local/bin/mkdir", 0x7ffd87aad0a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
  2769  [pid 17371] stat("/usr/bin/mkdir", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=51136, ...}) = 0
  2770  [pid 17371] stat("/usr/bin/mkdir", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=51136, ...}) = 0
  2771  [pid 17371] access("/usr/bin/mkdir", X_OK) = 0
  2772  [pid 17371] stat("/usr/bin/mkdir", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=51136, ...}) = 0
  2773  [pid 17371] access("/usr/bin/mkdir", R_OK) = 0
  2774  [pid 17371] stat("/usr/bin/mkdir", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=51136, ...}) = 0
  2775  [pid 17371] stat("/usr/bin/mkdir", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=51136, ...}) = 0
  2776  [pid 17371] access("/usr/bin/mkdir", X_OK) = 0
  2777  [pid 17371] stat("/usr/bin/mkdir", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=51136, ...}) = 0
  2778  [pid 17371] access("/usr/bin/mkdir", R_OK) = 0
  2779  [pid 17371] execve("/usr/bin/mkdir", ["mkdir", "/tmp"], 0x557ec7e15920 /* 5 vars */) = 0
```

My question is: Is it normal (and if so for what reason) is `/usr/bin/mkdir` `stat()`ed a lot? 
The output lines are numbered and in particular I wonder what sense will line `2776` make once `2771` was run already. Also I was under the impression bash could have saved all systemcalls from `2770` onward to the final `execve` as the `stat` should have provided the information at once? What am I missing?

I have since sought an explanation and checked how an alternative shell the `dash` shell would behave it also shows some `stat()`ing :

```
DASH$> strace -f sh -c "dash -c \"mkdir /tmp\" 2>&1 | nl | grep -e "execve\|stat\|access" 
[....]
  2792  [pid 17372] stat("/usr/local/sbin/mkdir", 0x7ffc66010b50) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
  2793  [pid 17372] stat("/usr/local/bin/mkdir", 0x7ffc66010b50) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
  2794  [pid 17372] stat("/usr/sbin/mkdir", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=51136, ...}) = 0
  2795  [pid 17372] execve("/usr/sbin/mkdir", ["mkdir", "/run"], 0x55d8d3453bb8 /* 6 vars */) = 0
```

I am aware that the lines `2792`,`2793`, similar to the lines `2767`, 2768`are because of searching the executable in the various directories in the current`PATH`.

If this is discounted then `dash` only does one single stat and `bash` does 10. Again raising the question: **is this normal?**

**UPDATE:**
There was more `geteuid()`,`getguid()`,`getuid()` and `getgid()` mingled in the bash stats

```
BASH$>strace -f sh -c "bash -c \"mkdir /tmp\"" 2>&1 | grep -e "execve\|stat\|access\|geteuid\|getegid\|getuid\|getgid" 
[....]
[pid 24534] stat("/usr/local/bin/mkdir", 0x7fffda480f30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 24534] stat("/usr/local/sbin/mkdir", 0x7fffda480f30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 24534] stat("/usr/bin/mkdir", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=51136, ...}) = 0
[pid 24534] stat("/usr/bin/mkdir", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=51136, ...}) = 0
[pid 24534] geteuid()                   = 1000
[pid 24534] getegid()                   = 1000
[pid 24534] getuid()                    = 1000
[pid 24534] getgid()                    = 1000
[pid 24534] access("/usr/bin/mkdir", X_OK) = 0
[pid 24534] stat("/usr/bin/mkdir", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=51136, ...}) = 0
[pid 24534] geteuid()                   = 1000
[pid 24534] getegid()                   = 1000
[pid 24534] getuid()                    = 1000
[pid 24534] getgid()                    = 1000
[pid 24534] access("/usr/bin/mkdir", R_OK) = 0
[pid 24534] stat("/usr/bin/mkdir", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=51136, ...}) = 0
[pid 24534] stat("/usr/bin/mkdir", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=51136, ...}) = 0
[pid 24534] geteuid()                   = 1000
[pid 24534] getegid()                   = 1000
[pid 24534] getuid()                    = 1000
[pid 24534] getgid()                    = 1000
[pid 24534] access("/usr/bin/mkdir", X_OK) = 0
[pid 24534] stat("/usr/bin/mkdir", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=51136, ...}) = 0
[pid 24534] geteuid()                   = 1000
[pid 24534] getegid()                   = 1000
[pid 24534] getuid()                    = 1000
[pid 24534] getgid()                    = 1000
[pid 24534] access("/usr/bin/mkdir", R_OK) = 0
[pid 24534] execve("/usr/bin/mkdir", ["mkdir", "/tmp"], 0x55adcd4dc040 /* 55 vars */) = 0
```

so maybe this can give a clue to what is "going on here" with bash?
Is doing some checking to prevent `setuid` exploits?

**UPDATE 2: **
The `geteuid()`,`getguid()`,`getuid()`, `getgid()` and access combo seems to be
the hallmark of using `glibc`'s `int eaccess(const char *pathname, int mode);` library function.
Each usage of `eaccess` incurs the use of all `geteuid`,`getguid`,`getuid`, `getgid` and `access`, since the bash's runs [findcmd.c](https://github.com/benolee/bash/blob/master/findcmd.c)'s `file_status` function which in turn runs eaccess twice like this.

```
#if defined (HAVE_EACCESS)
  /* Use eaccess(2) if we have it to take things like ACLs and other
     file access mechanisms into account.  eaccess uses the effective
     user and group IDs, not the real ones.  We could use sh_eaccess,
     but we don't want any special treatment for /dev/fd. */
  if (eaccess (name, X_OK) == 0)
    r |= FS_EXECABLE;
  if (eaccess (name, R_OK) == 0)
    r |= FS_READABLE;
```

where each eaccess might be linked to 4 syscalls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the loop in [`findcmd.c:find_user_command_in_path()`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/findcmd.c?id=64447609994bfddeef1061948022c074093e9a9f#n601).

`stat()` is called (from [`file_status()`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/findcmd.c?id=64447609994bfddeef1061948022c074093e9a9f#n116)) twice for each element in path: once via `find_in_path_element()` at line [640](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/findcmd.c?id=64447609994bfddeef1061948022c074093e9a9f#n640) and once via `is_directory()` at line [645](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/findcmd.c?id=64447609994bfddeef1061948022c074093e9a9f#n640).

As you mentioned, it's also in `file_status()` that `eaccess()` is called.

While that could be optimized, keep in mind that it's not big deal, because the path is then hashed, and all this searching and stat'ing happens only the first time a command is used.

Comment: It seemed to me that the hashing, while an effort to reduce iterating through `PATH` is not exempting the one file_status call in line [findcmd.c:365](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/findcmd.c?id=64447609994bfddeef1061948022c074093e9a9f#n365), if I am not mistaken. I have to look some more to reassure it is not wasteful. However it is to have your findings being somewhat to what I have found out in the meanwhile too. :) thanks!

Comment: Well, running it with `gdb` shows that a second call to `mkdir` will proceed directly, without any stat'ing.

Comment: You're right, running it with `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` in the environment will cause it to go through all the `file_status()` nightmare even when hashed.

Comment: What I do not get is, that there is a racing condition in any way. so why checking executability in the first place? why not simply `execve` early and react to any error encountered? Also any glues as to why `glibc` eaccess really does all the `stat` then `geteuid`, .... `access` (again) ? Seems like at least the last access could have been saved?

Comment: It seems that's the standard required behaviour ([Command Search and Execution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01) - point e.) Notice that searching is expressly required before attempting an execl().

Comment: the point e.i.a there is quite surprising, though. Other people may be of the same advice, see [here](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=854). As to glibc()'s eaccess, it just does all those syscalls. The rationale is probably that caching them is nearly impossible to get right in multithreaded programs, as any static/global variable would have to be protected with mutexes and such, which would be more expensive than a dozen light system calls.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code of bash](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/), the answer is:

**Yes** the calls are normal, they are due to several factors including

1. `bash` runs a function `file_status` that includes a call to `stat` and in most GNU/Linux setups two **seperate** calls to `eaccess` from `glibc`
2. `glibc`'s `eaccess` itself runs *again* `stat` and then the whole happy bunch of `geteuid`, `getegid`, `getuid`, `getgid` and finally `access` (as it might have not recorded any useful info from its inital `stat` and maybe glibc does simply not feel like saving on syscalls (context switches do not matter!).
3. `bash` wants to make certain that the file it found can iterrating through the directories in `PATH` are indeed executable and readable for the user attempting to do so. (one test)
4. `bash` runs a `hash` table to reduce searching path on successive invokations (the secont test with `file_status`)

This all then generates the numerous simingly superflous sys calls. 
6/11 syscalls for each cantate in PATH
and another 6/11 syscalls once the command was previously found to be in the hash-table and is hence checked for being still valid.

the `file_status` function in bash's `findcmd.c` looks in the case of my compilation for my linux box like this (i.e. the ifdefs evaluated)

```
int
file_status (name)
     const char *name;
{
  struct stat finfo;
  int r;

  /* Determine whether this file exists or not. */
  if (stat (name, &finfo) < 0)
    return (0);

  /* If the file is a directory, then it is not "executable" in the
     sense of the shell. */
  if (S_ISDIR (finfo.st_mode))
    return (FS_EXISTS|FS_DIRECTORY);

  r = FS_EXISTS;

  /* Use eaccess(2) if we have it to take things like ACLs and other
     file access mechanisms into account.  eaccess uses the effective
     user and group IDs, not the real ones.  We could use sh_eaccess,
     but we don't want any special treatment for /dev/fd. */
  if (exec_name_should_ignore (name) == 0 && eaccess (name, X_OK) == 0)
    r |= FS_EXECABLE;
  if (eaccess (name, R_OK) == 0)
    r |= FS_READABLE;

  return r;
}
```

which will run once `stat()` initially and the `eaccess()` twice which in turns (being `glibc` function runs :

1. `stat`
2. `geteuid`
3. `getguid`
4. `getuid`
5. `getgid`
6. `access`
   )

and hence is responsible for this part of the original bash output:

```
[pid 24534] stat("/usr/bin/mkdir", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=51136, ...}) = 0
[pid 24534] geteuid()                   = 1000
[pid 24534] getegid()                   = 1000
[pid 24534] getuid()                    = 1000
[pid 24534] getgid()                    = 1000
[pid 24534] access("/usr/bin/mkdir", X_OK) = 0
[pid 24534] stat("/usr/bin/mkdir", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=51136, ...}) = 0
[pid 24534] geteuid()                   = 1000
[pid 24534] getegid()                   = 1000
[pid 24534] getuid()                    = 1000
[pid 24534] getgid()                    = 1000
[pid 24534] access("/usr/bin/mkdir", R_OK) = 0
```